# How do I use MVC Validation to display a warning message without making the field required?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a asp.net MVC website where the user enters a social security number (SSN).  The client wants to display a warning message if the SSN is already used, but doesn't want to force them to change the SSN (there are conditions under which multiple records can have the same SSN).

The MVC code I inherited has a validation to check if the SSN has already been used.  The code works great.  If the user enters a SSN that is already used, a message appears saying "SSN already exists" and prevents the form from being submitted.  How can I change this so that the message is displayed, but so it doesn't prevent the form from being submitted?

**ModelApplication.cs**

```
    [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 9, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter 9 Digit SSN No")]
    [Remote("IsSSNExist", "Admin", HttpMethod = "GET")]
    public string ApplicantSSN { get; set; }
```

**AdminController.cs**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult IsSSNExist(string ApplicantSSN)
    {
        if (Session["viewapp"] == null)
        {
            if (obj_BllApp.IsSSNExist(ApplicantSSN))
                return Json("SSN already exists.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**Application.cshtml**

```
<label>
SSN
</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicantSSN, new { @class = "input-small", @maxlength = "9", @onkeypress = "return ValidateNumberKeyPress(this, event);" })<br />
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ApplicantSSNID, new { id = "hdnApplicantSSN" })
span id="spAppSSn" class="SSNmsg">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ApplicantSSN)</span>
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried using the response header like another poster suggested, but I couldn't get it to work.

This code didn't return anything and broke other javascript I had:

```
    $(function () {
    $("#txtApplicantSSN").change(function (xhr) {
        alert("Hello");
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', document.location, false);
        req.send(null);
        var headers = req.getResponseHeader("SSN-DUPLICATED").toLowerCase();
        alert(headers);
        alert("Goodbye");
    });
});
```

Using the same concept, I tried another way of getting the request header, but I never got a value.  It looked like the validation that set the header value was being called after the javascript.

```
    $(function () {
    $("#txtApplicantSSN").change(function () {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', document.location, false);
        req.send(null);
        var headers = req.getResponseHeader('SSN-DUPLICATED');
        $("#remoteMessage").text(headers);
    });
});
```

I tried something similar using session variables, but again the session variable seem to be getting set after the javascript code.

```
    $(function () {
    $("#txtApplicantSSN").change(function () {
        var someSessionVariable = '@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["SSNExists"]';
        alert(someSessionVariable);
        $("#remoteMessage").text(someSessionVariable);
    });
});
```

My current thought is to try to disable the validation when the submit button is clicked, but I haven't found a way to do it.  I tried this

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
```

in the controller but it never hits the server side code.  I get the validation error before it hits the controller.

**Update #2**

I disabled the validation when the submit button is clicked using the cancel class:

```
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary cancel" value="Save" onclick="javascript: return ValidatonCoApplication();" />
```

This fixes the problem for this field, but disables validation for all other fields.  Can someone suggest another way to do what I want without turning off validation?

In summary, this is asp.net MVC with Razor.  After the user enters a SSN in a text box, I need a message to appear on the screen saying whether or not the SSN is valid.  Currently I have a validation attribute in the model, but this is not only showing the message, it is declaring the model invalid and therefore not letting the user proceed to the next page.  I want the validation message to appear, but do not want the model invalid.  I'd appreciate any help you could give me.  Thank you.

Comment: If there are conditions under which the SSN is valid, why not test those conditions in the `IsSSNExist()` method and return ether `true` or `false`? And if the condition depends on other properties of the model, you can pass the value of those properties using the `AdditionalFields` property of `RemoteAttribute`.

Comment: The SSN is always valid, but the client wants a message telling the user if it has been used before.  Right now, the validation shows the message (correctly), but it says the model is invalid because of the validation attribute ([Remote("IsSSNExist", "Admin", HttpMethod = "GET")]).  Is there a way to return the message "SSN already exists" to the view without preventing the model from being invalid?

Comment: In that case, don't use the `[Remote]` attribute (which is for validation). Instead just handle the `.change()` event of the textbox, pass the value to a controller method, return a message and update the DOM with the message

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for responding.  I'm new to MVC.  I don't know how to right a javascript function that would call a controller method and return it.  All my interactions between the view and the controller comes from submit buttons on the view calling the method with a [HttpPost] attribute in the controller.  How do I pass a value from the .change() javascript to a controller and then return to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to display a message based on the value of `ApplicantSSN` (not invalidate the model), remove the `[Remote]` attribute, and instead handle the `.change()` event of the textbox to call a conroller method and return an appropriate message.

Controller

```
public JsonResult IsSSNExist(string ApplicantSSN)
{
  bool isValid = // your logic
  if (isValid)
  {
    return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  else
  {
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicantSSN) // remove the onkeypress attribute
// add a placeholder for the message
<span class="field-validation-error"><span id="ssn-message">The SSN already exists.</span></span>
```

css

```
#ssn-message {
  display: none;
}
```

Script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("IsSSNExist")';
var ssnMessage = $('#ssn-message');
$('#ApplicantSSN').change(function() {
  $.getJSON(url, { ApplicantSSN: $(this).val() }, function(response) {
    if(response) {
      ssnMessage.show();
    } else {
      ssnMessage.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Note: If the user enters an invalid value and tabs out of the control, the message will be displayed. You may want additional logic to hide the message if the user then starts typing in the textbox again in whichcase you would alo need to handle the keyup event

Comment: Thank you!  That worked great.  And now I know I can use the $.getJson function to access a controller from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can put validation in response header and then show it using jQuery as follows

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult IsSSNExist(string ApplicantSSN)
{
    if (Session["viewapp"] == null)
    {
        if (obj_BllApp.IsSSNExist(ApplicantSSN)){
            Response.AddHeader("SSN-DUPLICATED", "SSN already exists. ");
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

And add a span to display the remote message, and some jQuery in your view like following

```
<label>
     SSN
</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicantSSN, 
      new { @class = "input-small",  @maxlength = "9", @onkeypress = "return ValidateNumberKeyPress(this, event);" })
<br />
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ApplicantSSNID, new { id = "hdnApplicantSSN" })

 <span id="spAppSSn" class="SSNmsg">
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>m.ApplicantSSN)</span>

 <span id="remoteMessage" class="SSNmsg">
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>m.ApplicantSSN)</span>


$(function () {
    $('#ApplicantSSNID').rules()
        .remote.complete = function (xhr) {
        var responseMessage=xhr.getResponseHeader('SSN-DUPLICATED');
        if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.responseText === 'true') {
        jQuery('#remoteMessage')[0].innerHTML = 
              (responseMessage||'');
       }
    };
});
```

Note: please don't use Session in MVC. It's not a good practice.

Comment: Why use the header when you could return a json object with two properties valid and message?

Comment: @Bellash thanks for the help.  Thought your solution might work, but I could get it to do anything.  I tried a variation (see below), but it only returns null.  The validation seems to be firing after the javascript.  Any ideas how to fix that?             $(function () {
        $("#txtApplicantSSN").change(function () {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('GET', document.location, false);
            req.send(null);
            var headers = req.getResponseHeader('SSN-DUPLICATED');
            $("#remoteMessage").text(headers);
        });
    });

Comment: @matt_lethargic Returning a json object sounds interesting.  Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: Where you are returning true, replace that with an instance of a class that has two properties, 'Valid' which is a boolean and 'Message' that is a string

Comment: @matt_lethargic  Do you mean something like return Json(SOMECLASS, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ?  How would I then access that class from the view?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really do what you want in the way you want. Validation will pass or fail! What you'll have to do is remove the [Remote] validation attribute and do the check in the action you are submitting the form to. If the SSN exists then you'll have to pass this message out once you have completed the processing of the form.

Or use javascript and Ajax to check the SSN when the SSN textbox loses focus, then you can display the warning before the user submits the form

Comment: How could I use javascript or Ajax to check for the SSN?  I'm new to MVC and I don't know how to call the IsSSN method in the controller from javascript or ajax.  Can you show me how to do this?